# Is it possible to determine the total amount of timelocked Bitcoin?

Tags: blockchain, locktime

Now that is possible to lock funds until a certain date (https://coinb.in/#newTimeLocked). How to calculate how many of all bitcoin in existence is locked until a certain date? Any service that does this?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Tools like this use P2SH, which means the script which locks the output isn't visible until it has been spent. You can determine how much **might** be locked (total P2SH outputs for which no script is known) and how much **isn't** (total non-P2SH outputs), but you can't tell much more than that.